# Pump control - Uni or Bi polar stepper motor

Tags: stepper-motor, control, fluid-pump

I am working on a robot that includes several annular gear pumps. We are using the MZR 2521,

manual: (please see section 5.5) 
http://www.micropump.com/support_documents/manual_mzr-xx21.pdf

product page:
http://www.micropump.com/product_detail.aspx?ProductID=62

In the description they say that you can run the pump as if it were a stepper motor. This seems like it could be done perfectly with an Arduino, but I was not sure whether to treat it like a Unipolar or Bipolar stepper motor as the setup for each is quite different. Does anyone have any thoughts as to which it might be? Thanks so much.

Comment: Judging from fig.18 on p.22, this is a 4-wire bipolar stepper motor.  Neat little pumps, by the way.

Comment: From reading the datasheet, it seems you have to choose which type of motor you order, and one of the options is a bipolar stepper (section 5.5).

Comment: These pumps are the answer to a question I was just about to post. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Copying an answer from the comment:

From reading the datasheet, it seems you have to choose which type of motor you order, and one of the options is a bipolar stepper (section 5.5). –  Anindo Ghosh May 21 '13 at 3:31